# DataGrid.Columns.Count is always 0

Tags: c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I`ve a DataGrid where the Data comes from a DataSet and the DataGrid is set

```
 AutoGenerateColumns="true"
```

Now i want to add a column at index 6 through code with DataGrid.Columns.Insert(6, Column);

The Problem is that the DataGrid seems to have no columns. I`ve got the error that the index should be in the range.

When i tried to count the columns it show evertime 0. But i see all the data.

Is there a trick or why does the columns count equals 0.

Here is some code:
XAML DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"   AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumnHandler" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dgJournal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="8,65,8,30" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Blue" RowHeaderWidth="25" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Blue" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_CellDoubleClick" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" />
```

The Column that will be added:

```
private DataGridTemplateColumn CreateCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        MdlSettings modSett = new MdlSettings();
        DataGridTemplateColumn tempCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        tempCol.Header = "S";


        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox),"ownselect");

        DataTemplate voidTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        voidTemplate.VisualTree = factory;
        tempCol.CellTemplate = voidTemplate;
        Style chkBoxStyle = new Style();
        chkBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.check_CheckBox)));
        chkBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.check_CheckBox)));
        chkBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, true));
        chkBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(CheckBox.IsThreeStateProperty, false));
        tempCol.CellStyle = chkBoxStyle;


        return tempCol;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have the columns count after the datagrid is loaded, so you simply have to add

```
myDataGrid.Loaded+=(s,o)=>
{
   MessageBox.Show(myDataGrid.Columns.Count.ToString());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Columns comes in gridview after binding and you would be adding before that. You better add the column in data table and bind it with gridview.

Comment: I have set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid like: datagrid.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
         dataGridView1.DataSource = YourDataset;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "The name of the table inside your dataset";
```

Then try the rest .
It should work...

Comment: That is a DataGrid in WPF there ist no DataSource available i think.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your tag... If that's the case then @Adil is right

Comment: In WinForms i´ve tried that and it works very well. But WPF should be better for newer applications. But WPF seems more difficult as WinForms